# Data is not received from parameter. Return error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace')

Tags: typescript

I have gone through some similar questions, and I believe the problem I'm facing here is the data I try to pass is undefined. The thing is, there is another few pages that utilize this function, but it works well. Can someone please help me out spot the problem with my code?

```
const newPicPhone = stripPhoneMask(args.pic_phone_no)

const updateParam = {
    email: args.email,
    pic_name: args.pic_name,
    pic_designation: args.pic_designation,
    pic_phone_no: newPicPhone,
    pic_email: args.pic_email,
    bank_associated_name: args.bank_associated_name,
    bank_name: args.bank_name,
    bank_account_no: args.bank_account_no,
    first_time_login: today
}
```

And here is the function:

```
export const stripPhoneMask = (phone:string) => {
    phone = phone.replace(/\D+/g, '')
    if (phone.charAt(0) !== "0") {
        phone = phone.substring(1);
    }
    return phone;
}
```

Comment: `args.pic_phone_no` is undefined. You can check with `console.log(args)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figure out the problem and managed to solve it. What I did not mentioned in the question is that I have two same calling function which assign to two different variables. However, the second calling function does not carry any value with the parameter which makes it return the undefined error. What I did is, I set the condition for both calling function:

```
if (args.pic_phone_no !== undefined) args.pic_phone_no = stripPhoneMask(args.pic_phone_no);
if (args.site_pic_phone_no !== undefined) args.site_pic_phone_no = stripPhoneMask(args.site_pic_phone_no);
```